# 'I am married 'and' have two kids' OVER 'I'm married with two kids'

Tags: word-usage

> I'm married *with* two kids

Is that [expression written here](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2014/jan/17/cant-get-first-love-out-of-my-head) correct? Or it should be with a comma?

> *I'm married, with two kids*

If none of those are common, is it better to say...

> *I'am married and have two kids.*

Does *with* mean a simple *with* there? If yes, is anything possible that you carry when you are married?

> I'm married with a car 
>   I'm married with a pet 
>   I'm married with a pen
>
> All because when I got married, I carried my favorite things - car, pet and pen with me?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm married with two kids

is OK. No comma is needed.

As for:

> I'm married with a car
>   I'm married with a pet
>   I'm married with a pen

*with* implies some relationship between *married* and these things. Though you have them due to being married, it still seems a bit strange. Here its better to say:

> I'm married *and have a* car.
>   or
>   I'm married *and **now** have a* car.

*now* fixes the item time-wise to the married condition.

> I'm married and have two kids.

is also OK.

Comment: *comma not needed*, but what if I put?

Comment: The comma is not separating phrases, lists etc. as I would normally expect. I can't say the rule but possibly if you are trying to indicate a forced pause it may be OK

Comment: I've heard people saying "I'm married with a [insert pet species]" as a jokey reference to "I'm married with n kids".